# Why all objects are sliding? Concave polygon collision shape in godot 3

Tags: 3d, game-development, godot

I have a plane mesh. I just click on mesh -> create trimesh collision sibling
Then, I have a collision shape (concave polygon) and if i adding kinematicBody3d, or StaticBody3d, or RigidBody3d, etc. These objects are sliding (moving) on a surface (or not)

[image: that]

added object:

[image: and that]

after a few seconds

[image: and and that]

but if I change collision shape mode, it will work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the trees to move. Ever. Make them `StaticBody`.

If you want them to be affected by gravity and allow other things to push them, then use `RigidBody`.

Since you are using `RigidBody`, I presume that is what you want. Which leads to the question: How to make a `RigidBody` that does not move until something pushes it? Add it sleeping. The `RigidBody` has a [`sleeping`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#method-descriptions) boolean property that you can set to true to disable its simulation.

---

By the way, you can also change the `gravity_scale` of the `RigidBody`. Which means you could add them with [`gravity_scale`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-property-gravity-scale) set to `0`, and on the [`"body_entered"`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-signal-body-entered) signal, set `gravity_scale` to `1`.

And while we are at it, if using the `"body_entered"` signal is viable, another alternative to set the [`mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-property-mode) of the `RigidBody` to static, and change it o rigid on the `"body_entered"` signal. By the way, you would need to change `mode` using [`set_deferred`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set-deferred) or [`call_deferred`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-call-deferred) because you cannot change `mode` while Godot is doing physics resolution (which is also when Godot sends the `"body_entered"` signal).

*And yes, I know the [`RigidBody` modes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#enum-rigidbody-mode) are confusing.*

Answer (score 0):

Rigid bodies are effected by physics. To control this, there are several paramters. What I think you might be looking for is the **linear damp** property

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-property-physics-3d-default-linear-damp

If you set it to 60, you should stop the object in one frame

Comment: it's not working(

Comment: @Very_cool_programmier 

There are also a set of linear and angular axis lock properties. I fyou turn on all the axis locks the object can't move through space